# If you think you know me, you don't

Tags: riddle, science

> Settle arguments is my plight
>
> Tempted to see me? I'll likely die
>
> As it stands, this riddle has many answers
>
> Common of riddles, only one is right

**EDIT + Hints**

> Some people think this riddle is very vague. Trust me, it's not. "Only one" answer correctly satisfies all four lines of this riddle (oh, and the title too)

**Hint 2**

> I am born of brilliant mind

Comment: Based on the riddle content, it seems likely that this will be closed as *too broad*.

Comment: That is up to *interpretations* of the answer ;)

Comment: is "settle arguments" meant to be vague? is it meant to be "to settle", "settling" or "settled"?

Comment: @kedarguru my purpose is to, indeed, settle & offer some arguments. Well known ones, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you

> Schrödinger's cat

If you think you know me, you don't

> If you think the solution to the riddle is something knowable and definite, you're incorrect, since the cat is inherently an unknown.

Settle arguments is my plight

> The cat was a thought experiment intended to illustrate the ridiculousness of the Copenhagen interpretation, as part of discussion and debate between Schrödinger and Einstein. The cat is put into a deadly plight in order to settle the argument.

Tempted to see me? I'll likely die

> While the box is closed, the cat exists in a superposition of life and death. However if you're tempted to see it and open the box, observation will lead to a definite probability of the cat being dead.

As it stands, this riddle has many answers

> A reference to both the apparent ambiguity of the riddle and also the fact that all seem correct until the riddle is definitively solved, as if in a state of superposition.

Common of riddles, only one is right

> However, on solving/opening the box, one solution is determined to be the real one.

Hint 1

> "Only one" is in scare quotes, because though it's a single answer, it is also a superposition of two answers (an alive cat and a dead cat).

Hint 2

> Schrödinger was certainly a brilliant mind, and the cat, being a thought experiment, was literally born of it.

Hidden hint:

> The first letters of every line are STAC, or CATS backwards. (This relates to Hint 1, in that taking only one letter from all four lines spells out the answer.)

Comment: Uncover a final hidden hint and receive the correct mark ;)

Comment: Haha, think I got it!

Comment: Also, the title refers to something else. Hint: It is spoken by a fine man.

Answer (score 1):

2nd Attempt

Are you

> A perspective?

Settle arguments is my plight

> Different perspectives are used to settle arguments

Tempted to see me? I'll likely die

> Many people try to see from another perspective, but fail to actually do so. In this way, that perspective or point of view dies to them

As it stands, this riddle has many answers

> This riddle will be seen through many different perspectives.

Common of riddles, only one is right

> But only one perspective is the right perspective.

If you think you know me, you don't

> It's difficult for people to see other perspectives.

Comment: You offer a good guess, however my riddle offers another clue that lead to the correct answer and this one is not it :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are:

> A mystery

Settle arguments is my plight

> The predicament of a mystery is that it can be the subject of an argument, the resolution of which is in settling on the truth.

Tempted to see me? I'll likely die

> When you understand a mystery, it is no longer a mystery.

As it stands, this riddle has many answers

> The nature of a mystery is that there can be many potential answers.

Common of riddles, only one is right

> There is only one real answer to a mystery.

Title:

> If you know a mystery, it is no longer a mystery.

Comment: You offer a good guess, however my riddle offers another clue that lead to the correct answer and this one is not it :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you a

> Rebuttal?

Settle arguments is my plight

> Rebuttals are often intended to end the argument, or by forcing the other person to see from your point of view

Tempted to see me? I'll likely die

> If someone sees or understands the other person's rebuttal, their own rebuttal will die out.

If you think you know me, you don't

> Most people think they know what the other person's rebuttal will be, but more often then not, they don't

Comment: It’s wrong :) Your answer doesn’t seem related to the last two lines

Comment: I honestly thought the last two lines didn't relate to the answer, but the nature of the riddle.